# STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2-1 USB driver for macos?

Tags: usb, driver, st-link

I am trying to connect to my MacBook Pro the eval board: STEVAL STLCX01V1 from STMicroelectronics so I can try programming the SensorTile.

I am using OpenSTM (System Workbench).

Comment: What programmer are you using? That evaluation kit does not include one.

Comment: I think you are asking if I have a Nucleo board?  I do have one a Cradle Expansion Board as well as a Nucleo Board, I just  don't have it in front of me. I was hoping the Cardle Expansion Board that has a connector to the SensorTile could be used to program it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cradle expansion board cannot be used to program the SensorTile module. The USB port on this board connects directly to the module -- it's there so that you can program the module to behave as a USB device, and connect it to a computer.

You will need a separate SWD programmer to program and debug this part. Many of ST's evaluation boards, including most Discovery and Nucleo boards, have an integrated ST-Link programmer which will work perfectly. Remove the ST-Link jumpers on the other board, then connect the SWD pins between the two boards with jumper wires. (If you aren't sure of the pinout, check the schematics!)

**DO NOT** plug the Cradle Expansion Board directly into a Nucleo board using the Arduino shield connector. This won't work, and it might damage one or both boards.

Comment: Should OpenSTM and the Nucleo programmer board work on a macOS system?

Comment: Yes. I've worked with ST Discovery boards extensively using OpenOCD.

Comment: I have a NUCLEO-f401reT6 64 pins + a Nucleo Expansion board (X-Nucleo-IDB05A1) and a development Mac mini. What is the "Arduino shield connector?" I have a 5pin ribbon cable I can connect SWD between the CradleExpansionBoard (CEB) to SWD connector on the Nucleo-64, right? Only connect the Nucleo to my mac mini and not the CEB, right? Next, do I need to figure out if my OpenOCD can detect this Nucleo board?

Comment: As shown on page 8 of the [quick start guide](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/group0/45/b8/aa/c7/79/b4/4c/02/STEVAL-STLKT01V1%20Quick%20start%20guide/files/steval-stlkt01v1_quick_start_guide.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.steval-stlkt01v1_quick_start_guide.pdf) and page 14.